# Automize array object display from array database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array containing 10 objects. Each contains a question string, a `correctAnswer` string, and an object with 4 answer strings:

```
const DB = [
{
  question: "some question",
  answers: ["a", "variety", "of", "choices"],
  correctAnswer: "variety"
}, ...
```

I have a function which captures the user's answer via radio button input, and saves it in a variable:

```
function feedbackPage(){
  $('.js-quizform-questions').on('click', '.js-button-next', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    let yourAnswer = getFeedback()
    $('.js-feedback-page').show().html(evalCorrectAnswer(DB))
  })
}
```

You see that evalCorrectAnswer reaches out to the above database for validation. At the moment i am only able to display and validate the hardcoded first answer, which is dynamically generated like this:

```
function generateQuestionElement(item) {
  return `
    <h2>${item[0].question}</h2>
    <form id='form'>
        <fieldset>
            <div class='css-answers'>
                <input id='answer1' type='radio' name='answer' required>
                <label for='answer1'>${item[0].answers[0]}</label>
            </div>
            <div class='css-answers'>
                <input id='answer2' type='radio' name='answer' required>
                <label for='answer2'>${item[0].answers[1]}</label>
```

I need a way to automatically choose the first question, to include its answers and display it via `generateQuestionItem`. Then I need to take that question (& its answers) out of the pool and display the next question once i click on a `Next` button on the `eval` page. I have a hard time implementing this feature in an object-oriented way.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/HelleFl/pen/wjwwez)

Answer (score 1):

Construct a variable of

```
let questionNumber = 0
```

Then update the following line inside `renderQuestion`:

```
<label for='answer1'>${DB[questionNumber].answers[0]}</label>
```

Later create a function that updates `questionNumber` at each appropriate point.